# NVCC bug with gcc7

Tags: c++, cuda, nvcc

I have the following code and it has an error only with cuda9 + gcc7. Cuda9 + gcc6 doesn't have compilation errors.

This is a minimal reproducer I wrote for the error. I suspect it is a compiler error but I have to fix my code to work with gcc7. I want to know a workaround to get rid of the compilation error.

Cuda compilation tools, release 9.2, V9.2.148

gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-21ubuntu1~16.04)

Error:

```
$ nvcc test.cu
test.h: In constructor 'TestOp::TestOp()':
test.h:6:54: error: 'Dummy' is not a member of 'TestOp'
```

//op.h

```
   class OperatorBase {
     public:
      template <typename T>
      inline bool Dummy(T default_value) {
        return true;
      }
    };

    template <class Context>
    class Operator : public OperatorBase {
    };
```

//test.cu

```
#include "test.h"
```

//test.h

```
#include "op.h"
template <class Context>
class TestOp : public Operator<Context> {
 public:
  TestOp()
      : msg_(
            OperatorBase::Dummy<bool>(true)) {}

 private:
  bool msg_;
};
```

Comment: There are multiple versions of CUDA 9. What is the output of `nvcc --version` ?

Comment: Works for me. It seems the error message does not relate the code in the question.

Comment: I've updated my question with the cuda version. @RobertCrovella

Comment: I am going to go out on a limb here and say this is actually a gcc bug and not a problem with CUDA. Clang, MSVC, and every gcc version before gcc7 can correctly compile the code which the toolchain emits in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CUDA 9.2 nvcc C++ front end is doing this to your code:

```
class OperatorBase { 
    public: 
        template< class T> bool 
            Dummy(T default_value) { 
                return true; 
            } 
}; 

template< class Context> 
class Operator : public OperatorBase { 
}; 

template< class Context> 
class TestOp : public Operator< Context>  { 
    public: 
        TestOp() 
            : msg_(
                    this->OperatorBase::template Dummy< bool> (true)) { } 

    private: 
        bool msg_; 
};
```

It seems that g++-7 (and only g++-7 or newer) has a name lookup failure when compiling that code. I don't know enough about C++ to say why it fails and whether is actually should fail. I can say that this isn't new behaviour from the CUDA front end -- every version of CUDA 9 and CUDA 8 I have tested this with emits identical code.

You can avoid this by achieving name resolution in a different way:

```
template <class Context>
class TestOp : public Operator<Context> {
    public:
        TestOp()
            : msg_(
                    //OperatorBase::Dummy<bool>(true)) {}
                    this->template Dummy<bool>(true)) {}
    private:
        bool msg_;
};
```

While this is a bit old-school, it compiles with CUDA 9.2 and gcc-4.8, gcc-5.4 and gcc-7. There is probably a third solution you could try based around a `using` alias, if `this->` offends your sensibilities too much.